# Quicksort: Iterative or Recursive

Tags: algorithm, performance, recursion, iteration, quicksort

I learnt about quicksort and how it can be implemented in both Recursive and Iterative method.

In Iterative method:

0. Push the range `(0...n)` into the stack
1. Partition the given array with a pivot
2. Pop the top element.
3. Push the partitions (index range) onto a stack if the range has more than one element
4. Do the above 3 steps, till the stack is empty

And the recursive version is the normal one defined in wiki.

I learnt that recursive algorithms are always slower than their iterative counterpart.

So, Which method is preferred in terms of time complexity (memory is not a concern)?
Which one is fast enough to use in Programming contest?
Is C++ STL `sort()` using a recursive approach?

Comment: you have already answered yourself. Recursive version is shorter and more clear. Iterative is faster and makes you simulate the recursion call stack.

Comment: But my prof told that the recursion stack depth is same as stack which we use for storing partition range. So, how iterative one is significantly faster?

Comment: @sabari: Your assumption about recursive being faster is wrong. I statistically tested these assumptions and editted the answer with the results.

Comment: You can implement an iterative version of Quicksort with a queue rather than a stack.  There's nothing about the algorithm that requires the extra storage to be LIFO.  The stack approach is more similar to the recursive description commonly used for Quicksort, but that's not actually an inherent part of the algorithm.  It's perhaps likely that a LIFO structure will give better locality of reference, so it may be faster because it's more cache friendly.

Comment: I guess the difference is one of heap vs staxk space. Penalty for garbage collection is high.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**In terms of (asymptotic) time complexity - they are both the same.**

"Recursive is slower then iterative" - the rational behind this statement is because of the overhead of the recursive stack (saving and restoring the environment between calls).

However -these are constant number of ops, while not changing the number of "iterations".

Both recursive and iterative quicksort are `O(nlogn)` *average case* and `O(n^2)` *worst case*.

---

**EDIT:**

just for the fun of it I ran a benchmark with the (java) code attached to the post , and then I ran [wilcoxon statistic test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test), to check what is the probability that the running times are indeed distinct

The results may be conclusive (P_VALUE=2.6e-34, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value. Remember that the P_VALUE is P(T >= t | H) where T is the test statistic and H is the null hypothesis). But the answer is not what you expected.

The average of the iterative solution was 408.86 ms while of recursive was 236.81 ms

(Note - I used `Integer` and not `int` as argument to `recursiveQsort()` - otherwise the recursive would have achieved much better, because it doesn't have to box a lot of integers, which is also time consuming - I did it because the iterative solution has no choice but doing so.

Thus - your assumption is not true, the recursive solution is faster (for my machine and java for the very least) than the iterative one with P_VALUE=2.6e-34.

```java
public static void recursiveQsort(int[] arr,Integer start, Integer end) { 
    if (end - start < 2) return; //stop clause
    int p = start + ((end-start)/2);
    p = partition(arr,p,start,end);
    recursiveQsort(arr, start, p);
    recursiveQsort(arr, p+1, end);

}

public static void iterativeQsort(int[] arr) { 
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    stack.push(0);
    stack.push(arr.length);
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        int end = stack.pop();
        int start = stack.pop();
        if (end - start < 2) continue;
        int p = start + ((end-start)/2);
        p = partition(arr,p,start,end);

        stack.push(p+1);
        stack.push(end);

        stack.push(start);
        stack.push(p);

    }
}

private static int partition(int[] arr, int p, int start, int end) {
    int l = start;
    int h = end - 2;
    int piv = arr[p];
    swap(arr,p,end-1);

    while (l < h) {
        if (arr[l] < piv) {
            l++;
        } else if (arr[h] >= piv) { 
            h--;
        } else { 
            swap(arr,l,h);
        }
    }
    int idx = h;
    if (arr[h] < piv) idx++;
    swap(arr,end-1,idx);
    return idx;
}
private static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) { 
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}

public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    Random r = new Random(1);
    int SIZE = 1000000;
    int N = 100;
    int[] arr = new int[SIZE];
    int[] millisRecursive = new int[N];
    int[] millisIterative = new int[N];
    for (int t = 0; t < N; t++) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) { 
            arr[i] = r.nextInt(SIZE);
        }
        int[] tempArr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
        
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        iterativeQsort(tempArr);
        millisIterative[t] = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis()-start);
        
        tempArr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
        
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        recursvieQsort(tempArr,0,arr.length);
        millisRecursive[t] = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis()-start);
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (int x : millisRecursive) {
        System.out.println(x);
        sum += x;
    }
    System.out.println("end of recursive. AVG = " + ((double)sum)/millisRecursive.length);
    sum = 0;
    for (int x : millisIterative) {
        System.out.println(x);
        sum += x;
    }
    System.out.println("end of iterative. AVG = " + ((double)sum)/millisIterative.length);
}
```

Comment: Your test mainly is showing how efficient the Stack class is working, not how efficient the iterative version of quicksort is. You can use more a static, self written stack of for example 64 elements and the push and pop operations will be much faster. I guess that will be faster than the recursive one! And if you implement it the right way, you can sort 2^64 elements in the worst case, which is simply enough in practical applications.

Comment: @Argeman: Thanks for your comment. This is actually the point of the benchmark - the stack solution is very dependent on the stack implementation while the call stack is pretty much optimized for its purpose already, and thus a recursive solution is not likely to be worse then an iterative one, unless you spend a lot of time optimizing the stack for specific purpose (and I doubt the difference will be significant enough to worth the time). As I said, it is just a "fun test" - the main idea behind the answer yet remains - the *asymptotic* time complexity is the same.

Comment: P.S. The broken printing format (and not using `Arrays.toString()`) is to fit the input expected by the wilcoxon online calculator in http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/Service/Statistics/Wilcoxon_Test.html

Comment: @amit how did u run the "Wilcoxon signed-rank test"...Any tool that u have used ?

Comment: @Geek: I put the on-line tool I used as a comment (The one starting with P.S). PythonXY also has it implemented as [scipy.stats.wilcoxon](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wilcoxon.html)

Comment: i think it should be `stack.push(p-1);`

Comment: I repeated this experiment in C++, using an array and an index for the iterative quicksort "stack". There was maybe a 1% to 2% difference, with either being faster, depending on implementation specifics. An optimizing compiler may keep the array address in a register rather than pass it as a parameter in the case of a recursive merge sort. I sorted 16 million (2^24) pseudo-random 64 bit unsigned integers, and it takes about 1.35 seconds on my system (Intel 3770K 3.5 ghz, Win 7 Pro 64 bit, VS2015).

Comment: I must say one thing, I'm learning DSA right now and was having a hard time to understand how to transform recursive version of this algorithm to be iterative - and your example does this in a way that is really easy to understand by using an already defined Stack structure instead of reinventing the wheel as other examples that I've encountered do.

Answer (score 11):

Recursion is NOT always slower than iteration. Quicksort is perfect example of it. The only way to do this in iterate way is create stack structure. So in other way do the same that the compiler do if we use recursion, and propably you will do this worse than compiler. Also there  will be more jumps if you don't use recursion (to pop and push values to stack).

Comment: Why do you have to jump in order to pop and push?

Comment: If it's not inlined you (in most cases) need to call some functions, so it need to call.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you saying that using the runtime stack (recursive) is more efficient than a stack structure create by the user? @amit do you have any thoughts?

Comment: I think that it is less efficient. Because you need to alloc enough heap to build stack (or even realloc if you run out of free memory), you need to store position somewhere, you need to check against corner cases (empty/full stack), etc.

Comment: at sometime long ago i saw application crash due too many, and compiler limitation of recursion call , is it still the case in new days? what about the memory? just because hardware are better, doesn't mean we shouldn't care... just take a look at android world and you see how many application and service running, and some wrote by newbies, cause phone to crash...

Answer (score 1):

That's the solution i came up with in Javascript. I think it works.

```js
const myArr = [33, 103, 3, 726, 200, 984, 198, 764, 9]

document.write('initial order :', JSON.stringify(myArr), '<br><br>')
qs_iter(myArr)
document.write('_Final order :', JSON.stringify(myArr))

function qs_iter(items) {
  if (!items || items.length <= 1) {
    return items
  }
  var stack = []
  var low   = 0
  var high  = items.length - 1
  stack.push([low, high])
  while (stack.length) {
    var range = stack.pop()
    low       = range[0]
    high      = range[1]
    if (low < high) {
      var pivot = Math.floor((low + high) / 2)
      stack.push([low, pivot])
      stack.push([pivot + 1, high])
      while (low < high) {
        while (low < pivot && items[low] <= items[pivot])   low++
        while (high > pivot && items[high] > items[pivot])  high--
        if (low < high) {
          var tmp     = items[low]
          items[low]  = items[high]
          items[high] = tmp
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return items
}
```

Let me know if you found a mistake :)

> Mister Jojo UPDATE :
> this code just mixes values that can in rare cases lead to a sort, in other words never.
> For those who have a doubt, I put it in snippet.

Comment: this code just mixes values that can in rare cases lead to a sort, in other words never.
For those who have a doubt, I put it in snippet.

Answer (score 0):

> *So, which method is preferred ...?*

Neither, i.e. both at the same time. Modifying the `recursiveQsort` function from [amit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572670/amit)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12553314/849891), it is

```java
public static void recIterQsort(int[] arr, int start, int end) { 
    while (end - start >= 2) {  // iteratively,
      int p = start + ((end-start)/2);
      p = partition(arr,p,start,end);
      if( p-start < end-p)   // sort shorter part, recursively
      {
          recIterQsort(arr, start, p);
          start = p+1;    // "call" recIterQsort(arr, p+1, end);
      }
      else
      {
          recIterQsort(arr, p+1, end);
          end = p;        // "call" recIterQsort(arr, start, p);
      }
    }
}
```

Sorting one part recursively, we go on to sort the remaining part in a loop. This transformation is equivalent to performing the [tail call optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Relation_to_the_while_statement), eliminating the recursive call which is the very last operation in a recursive function.

Sorting the *shorter* part *first*, the depth of the recursion is guaranteed to be no bigger than `log(n)`, so recursion is not a problem. And the iteration does not have to do any bookkeeping manually with no `Stack`, so can just use `int` indices.