# Find second largest element in an array using recursion

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, recursion

As the title says, is there any efficient way to find the second largest element in an array using recursion?

Comment: show us your code and we tell you if it is efficient

Comment: Do you have to use recursion? It's rather easy to do without.

Comment: Efficiency and recursion are two different directions.

Comment: Assuming it's unsorted, the simplest way would be to run through the array once, find the largest element, then run through again to find the largest element less than the largest. You could use recursion; it would recurse twice.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard why pass twice if you can pass once?

Comment: @Sibi This claim is way to broad to be correct. Many times the attempt to avoid recursion causes programmers to mimic it using loop + stack - which results in a very less efficient solution. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553238/quicksort-iterative-or-recursive) for example.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore That would be more efficient, yes. I was going with simpler.

Comment: Yes, I have to use recursion. I was doing in the quicksort way as you suggested. But sorting the array to find the second largest element - isn't it overkill? That's why I used "efficient".

Comment: @Sibi,Using tail recursion,complier cound transfer recursion to loop,and have same efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[partition based Selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Partition-based_general_selection_algorithm) is recursive by nature**, and it lets you select the `k`'th element in the array, so using it - you can actually find the answer for any `k`, including `k = n-1` (your case).

This is done in `O(n)` on average with fairly low constants.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing is known about the array, you can't do better than `O(n)`, whether it's recursive or iterative.

Just pass throught the array recursively, while passing the two largest elements and replacing them if you find larger values.

```
find_largest(array_begin, largest, secondLargest)
    if (array_begin = NULL)
       return secondLargest
    if (array_begin.value > largest)
       secondLargest = largest
       largest = array_begin.value
    return find_largest(array_begin+1, largest, secondLargest)
```

`largest` and `secondLargest` can initially be set to the minimum you expect to find in the array.

You're right, sorting (at least full sorting) is overkill.

Comment: How can I set the minimum if nothing about the array is known? Do you mean the first elem?

Comment: @Neel no additional info I mean - i.e. if you know that the array is sorted, you can do it in `O(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Something in `O(n)` like this:

```
int findSecondLargest(int[] arr, int index, int largest, int secondLargest) {
    if(index == arr.length) {
        return secondLargest;
    }
    int element = arr[index];
    if(element > secondLargest) {
        if(element > largest) {
            return findSecondLargest(arr, index + 1, element, largest);
        } else {
            return findSecondLargest(arr, index + 1, largest, element);
        }
    }
    return findSecondLargest(arr, index + 1, largest, secondLargest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void recurs(int[] data, int ind, int max1, int max2){
        if(ind<data.length){
            if(data[ind]>max1){
                int temp = max1;
                max1 = data[ind];
                max2 = temp;
            } else if(data[ind]>max2){
                max2 = data[ind];
            }
            recurs(data, ind+1, max1, max2);
        } else {
            return max2;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

to call it : 
        recurs(dataX, 0, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE);

Answer (score 0):

Instinctively, you can scan the array and do comparison on every value twice. Anyway, you need O(n) to solve the problem. It's fast enough.

Try to avoid recursive when it is not necessary because it is not free.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it by recursion then at most you have to do 3(n)/2-2 comparisons but for a better solution, think this problem as a binary tree with n numbers of nodes. Then there will be n-1 comparison for finding largest and log(n)-1 comparison for second largest. But some argue that it needs n + log(n) comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
function findTwoLargestNumber(n,startIndex,largestNumber,secondLargestNumber){ 
         if(startIndex==arrlengths-1){
             return [largestNumber,secondLargestNumber];
         }
         
         if(largestNumber<n[startIndex+1]){
             secondLargestNumber=largestNumber;
             largestNumber=n[startIndex+1];
         }
        return findTwoLargestNumber(n,startIndex+1 ,largestNumber,secondLargestNumber)     
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).