# what is the advantage of recursion algorithm over iteration algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I am having problem in understanding one thing that when recursion involves so much space as well as the time complexity of both the iterative algos and recursive algos are same unless I apply Dynamic programming to it , then why should we use recursion ,Is it mere for reducing the lines of code that we use this , since even for implementing recursion , a whole PCB has to be saved during passing of control of function from one call to another ?

Although I have seen many posts related to it but still it's not clear to me that what is the major advantage of implementing recursion over iteration ?

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2185554/1915854 It is often easier to implement a recursive algorithm than iterative, in which you normally have to emulate the stack which the architecture provides you with for no additional coding.

Comment: Have a look at the thread [Quicksort : Iterative or Recursive](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12553238/572670). This is a specific case where iteration VS recursion is discussed, and as shown by a benchmark - it is not trivial to make the recursive as efficient as the recursive, since the machine's stack is significantly more efficient than a programmed one.

Comment: You can check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688019/recursion-versus-iteration

Answer (score 0):

> what is the major advantage of implementing recursion over iteration ?

1. **Readability** - don't neglect it. If the code is readable and simple - it will take less time to code it (which is very important in real life), and a simpler code is also easier to maintain (since in future updates, it will be easy to understand what's going on).

   Now, I am not saying "Make everything recursive!", but if something is significantly more readable in a recursive solution - unless in production it makes the code suffer in performance in noticeable way - keep it!.
2. **Performance**. Yes, you heard me. Sometimes, to transform a recursive solution to an iterative one, you need more than a simple loop - you need a loop + a stack. 

   However, many times, your stack DS is not as efficient as the machine one, which is optimized exactly for this purpose by hundreds of employees in Intel/AMD. 

   [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12553314/572670) discusses a specific case, where a trivial conversion of an algorithm from recursive to iterative yields worse results, and in order to outperform the machine stack - you will need to invest lots of hours in optimizing your stack, and your time is a scarce resource.

   Again, I am not saying - "recursion is always faster!". But in some situations, it could be.

Comment: Its about actually   running it on the machine and tehn realizing that iteration is faster than recursion but what about the running time complexity in asymtotic notations , is it not the same in both cases ?

Comment: In one thread it was mentioned that quicksort is faster in case of recursion while not in case of iteration so is it merely talking about the running time on actual machine or about asymtotic time complexity .

Comment: @RadhaGogia Look at the thread I linked to in the answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12553314/572670). It clearly states that asymptotic complexity remains the same.